# How to change Json structure in ADF dataflow

Tags: json, azure-data-factory

Im  using  ADF dataflow to generate JSON file but I'm not able to generate json as per the requiredment

In data flow of ADF i used aggregate and used collect in expression to generate below
[image]

[image]

my expresion is something like this

> collect(@( SQUARE_FOOTAGE=SQUARE_FOOTAGE,
> Baseline_efficiency=Baseline_efficiency,.......))

Json I created

```
"importEquipmentItem": [                       
                        {
                            "catalogid": "LITE",
                            "manufacturer": 24.37,
                            "model": "85401",
                            "equipmentRefId": "MEA-26627"                                                            
                          }
                       
]
```

and required Json structure is something like

```
"importEquipmentItem": {
                "equipmentRefId": "D063705559",
                "equipmentAttributes": {
                    "attribute": [
                        {
                            "attributeName": "catalogid",
                            "attributeValue": "129"
                        },
                        {
                            "attributeName": "manufacturer",
                            "attributeValue": "TNE"
                        },
                        {
                            "attributeName": "model",
                            "attributeValue": "TUH13VAC"
                        },
                    
                        
                    ]
                }
            }
```

I tried to find solution but did not find any related lead.

Comment: Can you provide your input data that you have given to aggregate transformation?

Comment: @RakeshGovindula its having 2 cvs files, one project and second measure, 1 project have multiple measures records in measure file

Comment: Ok, add the sample input data or provide the image of data preview of join transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the Json structure, you need to transform it with multiple derived columns

To achieve it follow below steps:

- My sample data
  [image]
- Now we will take a derived column and first create Json objects with below expressions

```json
Attribute1 : @(attributeName='catalogid',       attributeValue=catalogid)
Attribute2 : @(attributeName='manufacturer',        attributeValue=manufacturer)
Attribute3 : @(attributeName='model',       attributeValue=model)
```

[image]

- Now we will take another derived column to create `equipmentattribte` field with our above json objects.

```json
equipmentAttributes : @(attribute=array(Attribute1,Attribute2,Attribute3))
```

[image]

- Now we will take another derived column to create `importEquipmentItem` object with above derived column

```json
importEquipmentItem : @(equipmentRefId=equipmentRefId,      equipmentAttributes=equipmentAttributes)
```

[image]

- After this with select transformation delete all the excess columns except `importEquipmentItem` and store it in sink.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I did same using azure function, but thank you for the solution